# Equation for the multiplicity of a set of planes

Tags: group-theory, material-science, crystals

The multiplicity (m) of lattice planes counts the number of planes related to (hkl) by symmetry. For example, the multiplicity of the {100} planes would be 6 because the following planes are all identical for a cubic crystal system;

\begin{equation}
\ (100) \: (010) \:(001) \:(\bar100)\:(0\bar10)\:(00\bar1)
\end{equation}

For planes not involving 0 such as {hkl}, {hhk} or {hhh} I think the formula below based on permuting h, k and l as entities and correcting for repetitions works:

\begin{equation}
\ m=\frac{3!\times 2^3}{n!}
\end{equation}

where n represents the number of repetitions (*i.e* n=0 for {hkl}, 2 for {hhk} and 3 for {hhh}).

How can I generalise this for cases involving zeros? The problem I see is that: \begin{equation}
\ 0=\bar0
\end{equation}

Below is a table showing some more values for different sets of planes:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\ m=\frac{3!\times 2^{(3-N)}}{n!}
\end{equation}

N counts the number of zeroes present in (hkl)

n counts the number of repeated items (including zeroes) as explained originally